# Import local Node.js/NPM package in Deno

Tags: node.js, deno

I have a local Deno project which will depend on a separate local Node.js project.

I know I can import NPM packages using `import ... from "npm:foobar"` but what if the Node.js project is on my local machine? What then?

Comment: See [denoland/deno#18474](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/18474)